# Unable to properly read color data of UIImage created from UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, bitmap, uiimage

What's supposed to happen:

The user draws (using for example the Apple Pencil) into an UIView. When he's done, an UIImage gets created from that view, the ARGB data get read one by one and finally stored into NSData.

At a later date the NSData again get used to recreate the image. (I know I can achieve something similar much easier, but please just assume that there is a good reason for approach.)

What actually happens:

The user draws into the view, the UIImage gets taken, but when the code accesses the image data something wired happens: The data do not seem to fit to the image, which becomes apparent when they are being used to reconstruct the image.

And here is the code.

From the UIView

Initialisation

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing=YES;
        self.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Drawing

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    if (myImage!=nil) {
        UIImageView * iV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        iV.image = myImage;
        [self insertSubview:iV atIndex:0];

    }
    myPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [myPath moveToPoint:touchLocation];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    [myPath addLineToPoint:touchLocation];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        myImage = self.imageRepresentation;
}


- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    self.context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor]setStroke];
    myPath.lineWidth=3.0;
    [myPath stroke];

}
```

Getting the UIImage from the UIView

```
-(UIImage *)imageRepresentation{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    myImage= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return myImage;

}
```

Reading and transforming the image data

```
-(NSData *) pixel{

    int sidelength = (int) self.myImage.size.width;
    int numberData = sidelength * sidelength * 4;

    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.myImage.CGImage));
    const UInt8 * data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

    UInt8 pixel[numberData];
    for (int y=0; y<sidelength; y++) {
        for (int x=0; x<sidelength; x++) {
            int components = sidelength * y + x * 4;
            UInt8 a = data[components];
            UInt8 r = data[components+1];
            UInt8 g = data[components+2];
            UInt8 b = data[components+3];

            pixel[components]=a;
            pixel[components+1]=r;
            pixel[components+2]=g;
            pixel[components+3]=b;

        }
    }
    CFRelease(pixelData);
    return [NSData dataWithBytes:pixel length:sidelength*sidelength*4];;
```

From a different Class

Retrieving the picture using the NSData

```
-(UIImage *) getImage{

    UInt8 * pixel=malloc(sizeof(UInt8)*self.numberBytes);
    pixel = (UInt8 *) booleanData.bytes;

    const int Width = self.size.width;
    const int Height = self.size.height;
    const int ComponentsPerPixel = 4;

    const size_t BitsPerComponent = 8;
    const size_t BytesPerRow=((BitsPerComponent * Width) / 8) * ComponentsPerPixel;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef gtx = CGBitmapContextCreate(&pixel[0], Width, Height, BitsPerComponent, BytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host);

    CGImageRef toCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(gtx);
    UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:toCGImage];
    return image;


}
```

Here an example of the results:

The original drawing, rendered using "imageRepresentation":

[image]

The retrieved picture using "pixel" and "getImage":

[image]

I expect the culprit to be the 'pixels' method, because I checked its results and found them already to be pretty wrong. Also, I tested the 'getImage' in a different setting, and it worked just fine. But the strange thing is, that this is also true for 'pixels'. So is it possible, that the UIView gets rendered in a way that's different from, say, a png or jpg? I checked the documentation for UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions, but that didn't give me a uselful clue.

Comment: You're assuming your image is a square - its height equals its width. Are you sure this assumption is correct? Another thing:

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I initialise the view (as LetterView, a subclass of UIView) from a parent view like this: self.letterView = [[LetterView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.width)];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems. The first one is that you don't insert all the image data into `pixel` array in the `pixel` method.

If your image is 100x100 then the total number of bytes is 10000 multiplied by 4. In your `for` loop the biggest pixel that you get will be 100x100+100x4, which is 10400. The remaining pixels contain junk.

This loop will do the job:

```
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < numberData; i += 4) {
    pixel[i] = data[i];
    pixel[i + 1] = data[i + 1];
    pixel[i + 2] = data[i + 2];
    pixel[i + 3] = data[i + 3];
}
```

The second problem is more interesting. The recreated image will be twisted if its width is not a multiplication of 64. There is some sort of bug in `CGBitmapContextCreate` - I filed that bug to Apple about six years ago and they claimed they fixed it, but it can be easily reproduced under certain conditions.

I ran your code (with the new loop) and it works fine with a `UIView` of size 128x128, but returns a twisted image when the size is 100x100.

Comment: Wow, that first part verges on being an embarrassment. Guess I'll have to take lessons in counting. Thanks so so much! By the way, I added some code in the meatime, that converts the image into a png, and do not seem to come across that second problem. But anyway, if I do, I know now what to do.